# Spring cloud too many health check thread cause app down

Tags: spring

My Spring Cloud microservice is down and I dump the memory using:

```
/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jmap -dump:format=b,file=/my.dump 1234
```

and found about 300 threads of threads,the stack trace is:

```
qtp1016625178-1983
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (LockSupport.java:175)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt()Z (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(I)V (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(I)V (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
  at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await()V (CountDownLatch.java:231)
  at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet()Ljava/lang/Object; (BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:81)
  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block()Ljava/lang/Object; (Mono.java:1494)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans$ReactiveHealthIndicators.lambda$adapt$1(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/ReactiveHealthIndicator;)Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans.java:61)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans$ReactiveHealthIndicators$$Lambda$553.health()Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health()Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health()Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (HealthEndpoint.java:50)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SecurityContext;)Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/web/WebEndpointResponse; (HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:54)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor334.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (ReflectionUtils.java:282)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/InvocationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/InvocationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:294)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:355)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(Lorg/springframework/web/context/request/NativeWebRequest;Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(Lorg/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequest;Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V (ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView; (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView; (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView; (AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (DispatcherServlet.java:942)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (FrameworkServlet.java:897)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:645)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (FrameworkServlet.java:882)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:750)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHolder.java:873)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1623)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:214)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (WebStatFilter.java:123)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (CorsFilter.java:96)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (RequestContextFilter.java:99)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (FormContentFilter.java:92)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (TracingFilter.java:86)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:1610)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:540)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ScopedHandler.java:146)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (SecurityHandler.java:548)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ScopedHandler.java:257)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (SessionHandler.java:1701)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ScopedHandler.java:255)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ContextHandler.java:1345)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ScopedHandler.java:203)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ServletHandler.java:480)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (SessionHandler.java:1668)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ScopedHandler.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ContextHandler.java:1247)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ScopedHandler.java:144)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Request;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel;)V (Server.java:502)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle()Z (HttpChannel.java:370)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable()V (HttpConnection.java:267)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded()V (AbstractConnection.java:305)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable()Z (FillInterest.java:103)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run()V (ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(Z)Z (EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(Z)V (EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run()V (EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run()V (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run()V (QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Thread.java:748)
```

I am monitor the app using grafana,the app normal running about 90 threads.It grows up 200+ threads in half an hour.this is the monitor graphic(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMDXZ.png):

[image: monitor]

Why would this happen?

Comment: Given that they're all waiting on a countdown latch, I would hypothesize that one of the many queries that the health endpoint was attempting never resolved, blocking the thread indefinitely.

Comment: Check for the objects locked by threads between 8:25 and 8:40